# Why I use mapbox-gl-native in node cannot render text-field?

Tags: node.js, mapbox-gl

I used mapbox gl native to render PBF data in nodejs and wanted to display text field through symbol, but the rendered result did not have any text;

I used the example provided in the mapbox gl native repository

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var mbgl = require('@mapbox/mapbox-gl-native');
var sharp = require('sharp');

var options = {
  request: function(req, callback) {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'test', req.url), function(err, data) {
      callback(err, { data: data });
    });
  },
  ratio: 1
};

var map = new mbgl.Map(options);

map.load(require('./test/fixtures/style.json'));

map.render({zoom: 0}, function(err, buffer) {
    if (err) throw err;

    map.release();

    var image = sharp(buffer, {
        raw: {
            width: 512,
            height: 512,
            channels: 4
        }
    });

    // Convert raw image buffer to PNG
    image.toFile('image.png', function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

and the style.json

```
{
  "version": 8,
  "name": "Empty",
  "sources": {
    "mapbox": {
      "type": "vector",
      "maxzoom": 15,
      "tiles": [
        "./fixtures/tiles/{z}-{x}-{y}.vector.pbf"
      ]
    }
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "id": "background",
      "type": "background",
      "paint": {
        "background-color": "white"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "water",
      "type": "fill",
      "source": "mapbox",
      "source-layer": "water",
      "paint": {
        "fill-color": "blue"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "poi_name",
      "type": "symbol",
      "source": "mapbox",
      "source-layer": "poi_label",
      "paint": {
        "text-field":"{name}",
        "text-size": "12"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But the result is that the image does not display the text, what is the reason for this?

I also tried adding a graph link, and indeed, there will be a prompt that if the address of the graph file is incorrect, even if I change the address correctly, the text still cannot be rendered.